# How to query table partitions list using

Tags: hive, qubole

I need to programmatically query Qubole for the list of partitions for a Hive table. I can do this by calling [the correct API endpoint as described here](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/rest-api/hive_metadata_api/get_table_partitions.html), but I would like to use the [qds-sdj-java client](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-java) to do this (I am already using it for other things).

In looking through [the client's Javadoc API documentation](https://qubole.github.io/qds-sdk-java/apidocs/latest/), I don't see an option for doing this. Is there a way and I am just overlooking it? Is calling the endpoint directly the only option?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Hive Command Example Using QDS-SDK](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/qubole/qds/sdk/java/examples/HiveCommandExample.java) where you can pass **show partitions table_name;** query for your Hive Table.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: That's true and is a route I considered going, but requires parsing the results from the query.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the published Javadocs for the QDS Client are simply out of date. The actual library itself [supports list partitions](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/qubole/qds/sdk/java/api/HiveMetadataApi.java#L68) in [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/qubole/qds-sdk-java/commit/30c49cd16ed14319fc82065655ee8725efe11ebb).

```
InvokableBuilder<List<TablePartitionsAndLocation>> viewTablePartitionsAndLocation(String tableName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, Got it. Yes, We will update the javadocs for the QDS Client. Glad that you found the solution you were looking for.